# How to update post's content on post publish?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm making a plugin that needs to change post content before the scheduled post is published.

The post is first stored as scheduled, then when it changes its status from scheduled(future) to published(publish), I need to send a request to an API, get a response from it and insert the API response in the post content.

The thing is that I want the status transition to *"wait"* for the response - not show the post as published UNTIL the API response is inserted in the post content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

You can trigger an action when the post's status is changing from `future` to `publish`, which happens when the scheduled time arrives. Then, change it's status to draft, and make a request to the API. If the API replied, you can store the reply's content and publish the post. If not, then schedule it again.

```
function api_request_transition( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // Let's check for draft too, since we will set the status to draft if the API doesn't reply
    if ( ($old_status =='future' || $old_status =='draft') && $new_status =='publish' ) {
        // Set the status to draft for now
        $current_post = array(
          'ID'           => $post->ID,
          'post_title'   => $post->post_title,
          'post_status'  => 'draft',
        );
        wp_update_post( $current_post );
        // Get the content from the API
        $api_data = file_get_contents('URL HERE');
        // If the content is valid, add it to the post and publish it
        if ($api_data) {
            $my_post = array(
              'ID'           => $post->ID,
              'post_title'   => $post->post_title,
              'post_content' => $api_data,
              'post_status'  => 'publish',
            );
            wp_update_post( $my_post );
         // If the API didn't answer, run this process again in 5 minutes
        } else {
            // Pass the data to the cron job
            $args = ( 
                    $new_status, 
                    $old_status, 
                    $post ,
                );
            // Schedule this again for 5 minutes later
            wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 300 , 'api_repeat_request', $args);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'api_request_transition', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'api_repeat_request', 'api_request_transition',1 ,3 );
```